# XCode UITesting target creates separate executable on device

Tags: xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

I'm not sure whether this is intended behaviour, but is it normal for XCode (7.2) to create a separate executable on a physical device for a UITesting target, despite both targets having the same bundle identifier?

Comment: I've faced the same behavior! any news?

Answer (score 0):

The new created target by Xcode for UI testing should have another bundle identifier like com.apple.test.<*ui_testing_target_name*>-Runner

Comment: So if I want to run the UITests on the device, do I need a new provisioning profile?

Comment: Yes. You can use a Wildcard App ID, this allows you to use a single App ID to match multiple apps.